# change theme color angular material 2

Tags: angular, colors, themes, angular-material

I'm using Angular 2. I want to use different themes color from Angular Material.
In particular, I want to use a different theme for each slide I have.
But where can I change them?

Comment: You have create seperate css files that

Comment: And import theme.css file inside the css file

Comment: Yes I created 5 different file scss with my themes and I imported them in my angular-cli.json. But then I have only the last theme that I imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write `styleUrl` with css/scss file path  (Do this for all component you have in your project)  like this :-

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
    import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';
    import { Router } from "@angular/router";
    import { User } from '../Models/User.interface';

    @Component({
        templateUrl: '/Html/Account/Login.html',
        styleUrls: ['../Content/AppStyles/login.css']
    })

    export class LoginComponent  {

    }
```